# concatenate Strings from a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "GenerarPassword.h"

@implementation GenerarPassword

-(NSDictionary*) generarDiccionario
{
    NSDictionary* m_Dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"Dx", @"1",
      @"Om", @"2",
      @"Al", @"3",
      @"Na", @"4",
      @"Je", @"5",
      @"Ko", @"6",
      @"Ke", @"7",
      @"Fi", @"8",
      @"Re", @"9",
      @"Me", @"10",
      @"Mu", @"11",
      @"Ra", @"12",
      @"Lu", @"13",
      @"Lo", @"14",
      @"Ka", @"15"
      ,nil];

    return m_Dict;
}

-(void) printPassword:(int) password
{
    NSLog(@"%d",password);
}

/*Se genera la clave numérica*/
-(int) generarClave
{
    srand(time(0));
    int r = rand() %(9999-1000+1) +1000;
    return r;
}

//Esta función Genera el valor Aleatorio
-(NSString*) GenerarValor:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *valor = [[self generarDiccionario] valueForKey: key];
    return valor;
}

-(NSArray*) generarlistaletras:(int) numero
{
    NSArray* lista = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],nil];
    return lista;
}

-(void) imprimirArreglo:(NSArray*) arreglo
{
    int i = 0;
    NSString *str1 =@" ";
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        [str1 stringByAppendingString:[arreglo objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
} 

     // lista = [0,0,0]
      //lista[random.randrange(0,3)] = [GenerarValor(numero)]

      //for i in range(len(lista)):
     //       if lista[i] == 0:
     //             lista[i] = [GenerarValor(random.randrange(11,20))]
     // return lista
@end

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    GenerarPassword *Generar1 = [[GenerarPassword alloc]init];
    int clave = [Generar1 generarClave];
    [Generar1 printPassword:clave];
    NSDictionary* dict = [Generar1 generarDiccionario];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[Generar1 generarDiccionario] valueForKey:@"1"]);
    [Generar1 imprimirArreglo:[Generar1 generarlistaletras:123]];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

My idea is to print the array (the function imprimirArreglo), but when run the program I get this exception: Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: Can not determine type information for -[NSIntNumber (null)]; what i wanted was to print the array with format 0 0 0.

Comment: It looks a lot like you are a C++ or C developer who is trying to "have a go" at Objective-C development. While you can use C++ code in Objective-C projects I'd recommend starting from the beginning with Objective-C just to learn the basic syntax etc... It will make what you are trying to do much much easier than you are making it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I edited your code into something more sensible.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "GenerarPassword.h"

@interface GenerarPassword ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *generarArray;

@end

@implementation GenerarPassword

- (NSArray *)generarArray
{
    if (!_generarArray) {
        _generarArray = @[@"Dx", @"Om", @"Al", @"Na", @"Je", @"Ko", @"Ke", @"Fi", @"Re", @"Me", @"Mu", @"Ra", @"Lu", @"Lo", @"Ka"];
    }

    return _generarArray;
}


- (void)printPassword:(NSInteger)password
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @(password));
}

/*Se genera la clave numérica*/
- (NSInteger)generarClave
{
    return arc4random_uniform(9000) + 1000;
}

//Esta función Genera el valor Aleatorio
- (NSString *)generarValor:(NSInteger)key
{
    return self.generarArray[key];
}

- (NSArray *)generarlistaletras:(NSInteger)numero
{
    return @[@0, @0, @0];
}

- (void)imprimirArreglo:(NSArray *)arreglo
{
    NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arreglo componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
    NSLog(@"%@", string1);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    GenerarPassword *generarPassword = [[GenerarPassword alloc] init];

    NSInteger clave = [generarPassword generarClave];
    [generarPassword printPassword:clave];

    NSLog(@"%@", generarPassword.generarArray[0]);

    [generarPassword imprimirArreglo:[generarPassword generarlistaletras:123]];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

There are a few things I noticed.

First, if you're going to store value next to keys that are just counting numbers... then use an array not a dictionary.

Second, you're never actually calling the method `generarValor` so a lot of the code doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Third, you should really be using a property to store the array/dictionary in. You are repeatedly creating new dictionaries in your code.

The line `NSDictionary* dict = [Generar1 generarDiccionario];` is actually just wasting processor cycles because you're not actually using `dict` at all.

Fourth, variable names and methods should start with a lowercase letter, class name start with an uppercase letter.

Fifth, there is a lot of useless code here. I think I've fixed the problem, in your `imprimirArreglo` method though.

Sixth, format your code nicely when you put it onto StackOverflow. Pretend you're doing and exam for college. No one here is paid so the chance they'll struggle through code that's all over the place is very small.

Also, take a look through the code. I've made some improvements and changes to it to make it Objective-C code and not C++ code.